# Set height of lightning-textarea

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, textarea

Hi I am building one custom LWC component and I need to set the height of the lightning-textarea

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-m-vertical_medium">
        <h1 class="slds-text-heading_small">Various Textarea Examples</h1>
        <p class="slds-text-body_regular">The following examples show various ways to create a textarea component.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <h2 class="header">Basic Examples</h2>
        <lightning-textarea name="input1" label="Enter some text" ></lightning-textarea>
    </div>
</template>
```

I have tried custom class style attribute along with below but nothing can set the custom height. Any idea how to set the custom height to show more rows?

```
.slds-textarea{
line-height: 15rem;
height: 15rem !important;
}
.textarea-container slds-textarea{
    height: 15rem !important;
}
textarea{
    min-height: 15rem;
    height:15rem;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

In my case I was using **lightning-input-field** within a **lightning-record-edit-form** for a textarea field - using a design token in the CSS file of the modal component I was building adjusted the textarea size without any further customizations needed:

```
:host {
   --sds-c-textarea-sizing-min-height: 200px;
}
```

Design token mentioned here: https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/textarea/

Comment: https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/textarea/
Read this guide if interested

Comment: Can confirm, this works with `<lightning-input-rich-text>`

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

**HTML**:

```
<lightning-textarea class="textAreaBody"></lightning-textarea>
```

**CSS**:

```
.textAreaBody {
    --sds-c-textarea-sizing-min-height:175px;
}
```

Comment: This also works for <lightning-input-field>.

Answer (score 2):

I dont think this is possible in lightning-text area but you can simply use text area with slds class where you can specify rows attribute

```
<div class="slds-form-element">
<label class="slds-form-element__label" for="textarea-id-01">Textarea Label</label>
<div class="slds-form-element__control">
<textarea id="textarea-id-01" rows=10 class="slds-textarea" placeholder="Placeholder Text"></textarea>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks I already did this thanks for sharing I am looking for an answer why it is not possible

Comment: @AvijitChakraborty you can't style child components from parents (or siblings for that matter) due to LWC's use of Shadow DOM.